# please, how to code start-up behaviour in Delphi6?

Tags: delphi

I have an application, and I put a shortcut to it inside win+startup folder, and all is ok.

Now I wish to change this approach, by coding it, and so I have used the code listed at the bottom of this post.

The code inputs a key inside HKLM, but there is a windows error when system starts:

> Access violation at address 004815EB in module 'ap1.exe'. Read of address 00000000.

This error is similar on 3 different computers, running win xp or win 7.

```
procedure SetAutoStart(AppName, AppTitle: string; bRegister: Boolean);
const RegKey = '\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'; // Run or 
RunOnce
var Registry: TRegistry;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create;
  try Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      if Registry.OpenKey(RegKey, False)
         then begin
                if bRegister = False then Registry.DeleteValue(AppTitle)
                                     else Registry.WriteString(AppTitle, 

AppName);
              end;
  finally Registry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How, when and where do you call this `SetAutoStart()` procedure?

Comment: It is very disappointing that you neglected my question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised by the program that is executed on startup. It has nothing at all to do with the code in the question. You can verify that the code in the question behaves as expected by checking the registry entries using the Registry Editor.

You will need to debug the program that is being executed at startup. You won't be able to attach an interactive debugger. Instead you will need to use trace debugging.

Comment: program reads a file, and this file is always there. If i launch the application by clicking on its icon, everything is ok. But if i launch it by putting a link inside HKLM\..\RUN, or if a launch it by another application that uses ShellExecute, than it is no longer possible to read the file. Depending on launch conditions, the application may not be allowed to acces the file

Comment: Do some debugging, like I said. Find out where your code fails. Find out why. All possible with trace debugging. If I had to guess I'd say you used relative paths and the working directory is not what you expected. Don't use relative paths. Use absolute paths.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In case you are interested the issue turned out to be use of relative paths. Changing startup mechanism changed the working directory.